# After Super+L one of my monitors stays off

Tags: 20.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, suspend, monitor

I'm writing this question from my second monitor because my main monitor stays black after trying to log back in after <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. However, this only occurs to me after being logged out for a longer time.

The funny thing is that I can log back in without actually seeing anything and after that I can move things to my second monitor (like the browser and Ask Ubuntu) and use them normally while my main monitor stays dark.

This also occurs on my laptop that has the same version of Ubuntu installed.

What I tried up to this point:

- Go from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> back to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> which was suggested in another thread.
- Writing `setx -dpms` into my `.xinitrc` file which was suggested in another thread.

Comment: Next time try turning off then on again that monitor.

Comment: This actually worked in some cases. But not consistently. Also this wouldn't work on my laptop.

Comment: There's really nothing else you can do, unless you have Nvidia graphics without the Nvidia proprietary drivers. That being the case then yes, it's plausible to consider software (drivers and graphics software stack) to have partial or "flimsy" support for external monitors. Installing the recommended drivers should improve the situation.That not being the case then unfortunately you have to live with it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm gonna try that. I have no idea why, but pressing Super and opening about fixed it for me rn. Fucking Nvidia

Comment: Please keep language clean.

Comment: You've not been specific on your OS & release details (i assume Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop as you state only 20.04).  Is this issue new? how old is your installation?   f this only occurred last 4-5 days then it's likely you're using the HWE stack and it is the bump from 20.10's stack (5.8) to 21.04's (5.11) which can be avoided by using the GA stack choice (ie. remain on 5.4 which is the *stable* choice); but as you provided no specific details I'm only guessing (some installations default to the GA stack so I maybe completely off-base...)

Comment: Pardon me for my prior language. Yes, I am using 20.04 LTS. I made a bootstick maybe a month ago on vacation to install Ubuntu on my laptop, so I can get used to it. Already at this point, I had issues with this. Now, back at home and having a nice workflow with Ubuntu, I decide to install it also onto my desktop PC. I have no clue if that's an issue, but I used the same bootstick. I have now installed a NVIDIA driver, I will although have to let my PC rest for a while to see if this solved the problem. And I will inform myself about HWE and GA because I have no clue what that is.

Comment: The command `uname -r` will tell you the kernel you are using; 20.04 has two kernel stacks as I said before; the GA kernel is 5.4 which is supported the entire life of the product; it's default for 20.04 Server & some *flavors* if 20.04 & 20.04.1 media is used for install however 20.04 Desktop defaults to the HWE kernel stack option (*flavor* installs of 20.04.2 media & later use HWE too). Wiki pages can be found at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack & https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers, I installed the proprietary NVIDIA drivers and it looks like it worked. I got some Linux books, looks like a just started a looooong journey.